# How to add source maps to Sentry on NextJs app with custom server?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, sentry, source-maps

After reading some Github issues I have added this webpack plugin into my `next-config.js`

```
            new SentryWebpackPlugin({
                include: ['.', '.next'],
                ignoreFile: '.sentrycliignore',
                ignore: ['node_modules', 'webpack.config.js'],
                configFile: 'sentry.properties',
                release: buildId,
                urlPrefix: '~/_next',
            }),
```

After adding this my source maps are being uploaded to the sentry. (Screenshot below)

[image]

But still, in error, it is not showing the source map and showing chunks only. How to fix this?

[image]

EDIT 1 :

After adding

```
config.devtool = 'source-map';
```

This is what Sentry is showing.

[image]

Comment: what's your webpack `devtool` setting?

Comment: After adding devtool to 'source-map'. There is some changes in source maps but still it is minified by webpack, 

Changed Screenshot is added in original question in EDIT 1